# linear transformations of same form

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers and $\mathbb{F}$ be a field . Let $f_1 , . . . , f_n$ be linear functionals on $\mathbb{F}^n$ . For any element $a$ in $\mathbb{F}^n$ ,define :
  $$T(a) = ( f_1(a) , . . . , f_n(a) )$$ 
how to prove $T$ is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{F}^n$ to $\mathbb{F}^m$ and how to show every linear transformation from $\mathbb{F}^n$ to $\mathbb{F}^m$ is of the above form for some $f_1 , f_2 , . . .   , f_n$ .

Comment: Thank you @Gianluca for the edit

Comment: You are welcome ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T: \mathbb{F}^n \to \mathbb{F}^m$ be a linear transformation. Given a vector $v \in \mathbb{F}^n$, let $T_i(v)$ denote the $i^{th}$ entry of the vector $T(v)$.

Claim: $T_i(v)$ is a linear functional.

1) $T_i(v+w)$ is the $i^{th}$ entry of $T(v+w) = T(v) + T(w)$. Thus $T_i(v+w) = T_i(v) + T_i(w)$.

2) If $c \in \mathbb{F}, \ T_i(cv)$ is the $i^{th}$ entry of $T(cv)=cT(v)$. So $T_i(cv) = cT_i(v)$.

Therefore $T_i$ is a linear functional.

By definition, $T(v) = (T_1(v),\dots,T_m(v))$.

Comment: Its from F^n to F^m dimensions are different

Comment: I assumed that was just a typo since you listed n linear functionals.  It doesn't change the proof, just switch most of the n's to m's. I'll fix it.

Comment: fi's are linear functionals on F^n i.e. fi : F^n -> F are linear functionals ..

Comment: If your vector has $n$ entries then it is in $F^n$. So if $T(a) = (T_1(a), \dots, T_n(a))$, the transformation goes to $F^n$. 

If you want it to go to $F^m$, you use $m$ linear functionals $f_1,\dots,f_m: F^n \to F$. So $T(a) = (f_1(a),\dots, f_m(a))$.

Comment: I proved T a linear transformation like here T(la+mb)=(f1(la+mb),...,fn(la+mb))=(f1(la),...,fn(la))+(f1(mb),...,fn(mb))=l(f1(a),...,fn(a))+m(f1(b),...,fn(b))

Comment: You are misunderstanding what I am trying to get at. Based off of the way you phrased your question, I assumed the $\mathbb{F}^m$ was a typo. I fixed my answer though, so the proof I have above is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I proved T a linear transformation like here $$T(la+mb)=(f1(la+mb),...,fn(la+mb))=(f1(la),...,fn(la))+(f1(mb),...,fn(mb))=l(f1(a),...,fn(a))+m(f1(b),...,fn(b))=lT(a)+mT(b)$$ ...  but m  confused since its fro F^n to F^m

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39390/discussion-between-kduna-and-ripan-jeet).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39422/discussion-between-shona-and-kduna).

Comment: Thank you for helping kduna i understood now .. and sorry for the trouble ..